# Query a Firestore Collection using Angular Fire & Angular Js

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I need to query the data from the firestore collection in Angularjs.

I already get the data from firestore using this code in the vanilla javascript.

```
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc,getDocs, collection } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.9/firebase-firestore.js";

const db = getFirestore();
 const snap =   await getDoc(doc(db, 'collectionname', 'docID'));
```

But I need to use this code in the angular js controller. I have already added the angular fire file. If I add the import file in the angular js file getting an error.
In angular fire docs, I did not see any methods.

Controller

```
var app = angular.module('App', ['firebase']);
app.controller('MainController', function ($scope,$firebaseObject) {
 const db = firebase.Firestore();
 console.log(db);
 const db = $firebaseObject.Firestore();
  console.log(db);
});
```

try both ways to access firestore but no luck.

I added the CDN link of firestore, firebase, angular fire.